# Change the behavior of a filter on a standard unmanaged query

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap, cds

I have added a field to the **Supplier List** Fiori app by extending the underlying CDS views `C_SupplierList` and `C_Supplier`. This new field holds a concatenation of the Supplier's Industry sectors in a string. It is fetched from a table function. The data is fetched correctly. The problem is that the filter for that field acts upon a string: if the user types an industry code in the filter, the returned suppliers are the ones having only this industry. If a supplier has the requested industry plus any other one, the concatenated string does match the filter and the supplier is not returned.

I would like to change the behavior of the filter to act as "Covers pattern" even when the user has selected "Equals to".

However, since the top CDS view `C_SupplierList` is an [unmanaged query](https://help.sap.com/docs/ABAP_PLATFORM_NEW/fc4c71aa50014fd1b43721701471913d/254f68c7d5374e94a88241b7ce3bd414.html), I don't know how to change the behavior of the filter without modifying the implementing class `CL_FAP_SUPPLIER_LIST_V2`.

I've tried to use annotation `@ObjectModel.filter.transformedBy:` on the Industry codes field in the extension of `C_SupplierList`. However, that annotation seems to be incompatible with managed queries. When I'm trying to access the tile I get the following error from the Gateway:

> Usage of annotation OBJECTMODEL.VIRTUALELEMENTCALCULATEDBY without
> annotation OBJECTMODEL.FILTER.TRANSFORMEDBY on element INDUSTRIES is
> not allowed

I've tried to make the new field a calculated Virtual Element by adding the following annotations and creating a calculating class:

```
  @ObjectModel.readOnly: true
  @ObjectModel.virtualElement:true
  @ObjectModel.virtualElementCalculatedBy: 'ABAP:ZCL_BUPA_INDUSTRIES_CALC_EXIT'
  @ObjectModel.filter.transformedBy: 'ABAP:ZCL_BUPA_INDUSTRIES_FILTER'
```

But the Gateway gives the following error:

> Annotation OBJECTMODEL.VIRTUALELEMENTCALCULATEDBY is not allowed for
> current entity type with OBJECTMODEL.QUERY.IMPLEMENTEDBY

The only left choice seems to be to edit the Implementing class for the unmanaged query, but it is a standard SAP object and I don't want to touch it. Is it possible to extend it ? Is there another way to change the default filter's behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you believe that setting up the @Search using standard annotations is not possible directly in CDS `C_SupplierList`, I took a brief look at the code and found that I could enhance the method `CL_FAP_SUPPLIER_SEL_BUILDER_V2->if_fap_supplier_sel_builder_2~prepare_where_clause`. I would suggest checking for the Fieldname and setting the filter accordingly.

Comment: Thanks ! I've enhanced the end of that method to replace `INDUSTRIES = '...'` with `INDUSTRIES LIKE '%...%'` in `cv_where_clause`.